# Notepad ++ Make Ip Address subnet Ex = ?.?.?.?/24 How?

Tags: networking, router, ip, notepad++

Hi guys i have a mikrotik router and i am trying to trace all the game server yet i did it but changing the subnet of the last period of the ip address is frustrating as hell. Is there a way that Notepad++ can identify the last period of the ip address?

For example: 150.109.234.191

Output: 150.109.234.0/24

Comment: It's dangerous to assume all networks are /24

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\b(?:\d+\.){3}\K\d+\b`
- Replace with: `0/24`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\b          # word boundary
(?:         # non capture group
    \d+       # 1 or more digits
    \.        # a dot
){3}        # end group, must appear 3 times
\K          # forget all we have seen until this position
\d+         # 1 or more digits
\b          # word boundary
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Yooo Thank you very much! You saved me from this frustration!

Comment: @WangYeo: You're welcome, glad it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex like this :

Find what : `[^.]*$`

Replace with : 0/24

Pointer should be position on first line character.